Issues with SSL Authentication Using Multiple Certificates in MySQL Client (MySQL Java Connector)
I'm working with two MySQL servers, both of which are authenticated using SSL. On the client side, I have successfully connected to the first MySQL server after adding one certificate to the keystore. However, when I add another certificate to the same keystore for the second MySQL server, I'm no longer able to connect to either of the MySQL servers.
The issue only occurs when I use the MySQL Java Connector. If I switch to the MariaDB Java Connector, I can successfully connect to both MySQL servers using SSL without any issues.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem when using multiple certificates in a single keystore with the MySQL Java Connector? How can I ensure proper connection to both MySQL servers with different certificates while using the MySQL Java Connector?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
